Writing all null string values as empty string in Spring app RestController responses
I have a Spring app that has a react front end. The front end wants null string values to be represented as "" instead of null. Is there a way to do this without having to annotate every string field in my project (and remembering to annotate every future string value in my DTOs)?
I was hoping that I could register a custom String Serializer that would just output "" if the value is null, but the StringValueSerializer is not called when the value is null. All null values go directly to the NullValueSerializer, and by the time you get to the NullValueSerializer there is no way to determine what field has a null value (or what type of field it is).

Once I figured out the NullValueSerializer problem, I had to figure out how to customize the SerializerProvider, which proved more challenging than I'd hoped in the mix of Spring, Spring-MVC, and Jackson.
First I created this new SerializerProvider implementation. It overrides the findNullValueSerializer, which is where we can look at the property type that is being serialized, not just the value. It just looks to see if the property type is a String, and if so gives a serializer that simply writes "", otherwise it let's the regular NullValueSerializer work. This means that any non-string (Long, Date, Object, Collection) will still have the 'correct' behavior of outputting null, {}, or [] instead of "". The problem I have seen with some other solutions is they would output "" for a null collection.
package com.mycompany.internal;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.*;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.SerializerFactory;

import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * Customization to write "" instead of 'null' when a string value is null in our JSON response to the front end.
 */
public class NullStringFriendlySerializerProvider extends DefaultSerializerProvider {

    public NullStringFriendlySerializerProvider(DefaultSerializerProvider provider) {
        super(provider);
    }

    public NullStringFriendlySerializerProvider(SerializerProvider src, SerializationConfig config, SerializerFactory factory) {
        super(src, config, factory);
    }

    /**
     * Magic that writes an empty string instead of null for null string values.
     */
    JsonSerializer<Object> nullAsEmptyStringSerializer = new JsonSerializer<>() {
        @Override
        public void serialize(Object o, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException {
            jsonGenerator.writeString("");
        }
    };

    /**
     * The really real magic that only uses the null string serializer if the field is of type string.
     *
     * @param property the property (not the value) that is being serialized
     * @return the serializer to use for the property.
     * @throws JsonMappingException if bad things happen
     */
    @Override
    public JsonSerializer<Object> findNullValueSerializer(BeanProperty property) throws JsonMappingException {
        if (String.class.equals(property.getType().getRawClass())) {
            return nullAsEmptyStringSerializer;
        } else {
            return super.findNullValueSerializer(property);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Needed for the abstract implementation
     *
     * @param serializationConfig dunno
     * @param serializerFactory   dunno
     * @return our instance.
     */
    @Override
    public DefaultSerializerProvider createInstance(SerializationConfig serializationConfig, SerializerFactory serializerFactory) {
        return new NullStringFriendlySerializerProvider(this, serializationConfig, serializerFactory);
    }
}

Once you have that class in place, you need to set it up on the ObjectMapper. I did not have any luck with other options that are mentioned online, but I did get this working in my spring boot application. It is a hook that allows you to customize the ObjectMapper.
@Configuration
public static class JacksonConfig {
    
    /**
     * We need to configure with this implementation so that we write a null value in a string field as empty string instead of null.
     *
     * @return the builder customizer.
     */
    @Bean
    public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer customizeObjectMapper() {
        return builder -> builder.postConfigurer(mapper -> {
                    mapper.setSerializerProvider(new NullStringFriendlySerializerProvider((DefaultSerializerProvider) mapper.getSerializerProvider()));
                }
        );
    }
}

